# How to avoid logging file contents on an insert or update query to a table with varbinary field

Tags: php, logging, cakephp

I have project with CakePHP 3.4 with MSSQL database and a table with a column varbinary where i store pdf content. But every insert or update on that table produces a log with the full file content.

Is there a way to log the query for debug but without all the content of the file?

My debug.log file are getting huge and producing a lot of debug.log.{timestamp} files because of that.

A sample of my debug.log:

```
2019-07-29 10:08:23 Debug: duration=0 rows=0 BEGIN
2019-07-29 10:08:23 Debug: duration=2 rows=-1 INSERT INTO 
xxxxx (id, binario, xxx_id, 
yyy_id, descricao, data_hora) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES 
('161802310', '%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
4 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 20098/O 6/E 15874/N 1/T 19972/H [ 556 149]>>
endobj

xref
4 13
0000000016 00000 n
0000000705 00000 n
0000000765 00000 n
0000000891 00000 n
0000001060 00000 n
0000001197 00000 n
0000002949 00000 n
0000003091 00000 n
0000003228 00000 n
0000003367 00000 n
0000003507 00000 n
0000015825 00000 n
0000000556 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 17/Prev 19962/Root 5 0 R/Info 3 0
```

And that continues until the end of file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The content of that file IS part of the query, so no.

Comment: You would have to parse the query and then remove that part of it. Generally speakin its a bad habit to save files to database. Store them in a common location and save the path into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, on CakePHP 4.0.5 they solved this problem:

https://bakery.cakephp.org/2020/03/28/cakephp_405_released.html

```
Binary data in SQL query logs is now encoded as hexadecimal to improve readability of query logs.
```